# Workaround for zero-sized arrays in standard C++14?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I am developing a binding toolkit for Google's V8 ECMAScript engine.
Consider this templated function:

```
    template<class... Types> void call_v8_function(v8::Local<v8::Function> function,
                                                   Types... args) {
        ...significant amount of context set-up here...

        v8::Local<v8::Value> call_args[] = { V8Utils::to_js_value(isolate, args)... };

        function->Call(this->context, sizeof...(args), call_args);
    }
```

It takes a variable number of arguments and maps them to an array of v8::Value objects using a helper function. (the arguments can have arbitrary types, as long as they're recognized by `to_js_value`) This works wonderfully when I compile using GCC or Clang.

In Visual Studio, however, it completely breaks down. When this templated function is called without any additional arguments, an array of size 0 is being declared. While accepted by GCC and Clang, the standard doesn't permit this and Visual Studio rightfully spits out `error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0`.

Because I find this approach to be very convenient, I'm looking for a way to make it work, other than duplicating the function for the no-arguments case, as that would lead to a significant code duplication.

Comment: You could try `std::array` which already has a specialization for zero-sized arrays (and `std::array::data()` also seems [fine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) for empty arrays)

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I need. Wanna add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: ,...or create a dynamically allocated array, you can declare such arrays with a length of `0`. Though using `std::array` is probably your best choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of c-style array, you could use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which already has a specialization for zero-sized arrays. Furthermore, for your function call the `data()` member is also [well-behaved](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) for empty arrays.